# How to call components recursively and keep track of nested levels in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, recursion

I have a component called '**CommentList**' and '**Comment**'.  CommentList is rendering comments by calling 'Comment' by using map (Say for example loop runs 10 times).

Now, 'Comment' can render 'CommentList' with new set of props again if you tap on any listed comment. So, It is like a nested thing.  For each deeper level I have Indentation. Like if you tap on first comment It's gonna call 'CommentList' and list its own 10 comments with some indentation and so on.

I wanna keep track of the nested level and entirely clear the List if user is 5 levels deep and start the same behaviour freshly from 6th level on the screen.

I also wanna have a back button on a new screen to go back  to first Set (1 to 5) once we are at a new screen with new set (6 to 10)

I'm gonna use functional components only. How should I approach to this problem, I will include the code once I get some idea to implement this. Any thoughts will be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

The following is the basic idea to get you started with a recursive approach. This is the root container of comments.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import CommentsList from "./CommentsList";
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentLevel: 0,
      comments: [
        {
          level: 0,
          comment: {
            text: "level 0 and comment one",
            comments: [
              {
                level: 1,
                comment: {
                  text: "level 1 and comment one",
                  comments: []
                }
              },
              {
                level: 1,
                comment: {
                  text: "level 1 and comment two",
                  comments: []
                }
              },
              {
                level: 1,
                comment: {
                  text: "level 1 and comment three",
                  comments: []
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          level: 0,
          comment: {
            text: "level 0 and comment two",
            comments: []
          }
        },
        {
          level: 0,
          comment: {
            text: "level 0 and comment three",
            comments: []
          }
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", marginTop: 100 }}>
        <Text>This is the rootview</Text>
        <CommentsList comments={this.state.comments} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The following is your CommentsList component.

```
import React from "react";
import { View, FlatList } from "react-native";
import Comment from "./Comment";

const CommentsList = props => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <FlatList
        data={props.comments}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
          return <Comment comment={item.comment} level={item.level} />;
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default CommentsList;
```

and the following is your Comment component. since it is recursive it will contain CommentsList component.

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import CommentsList from "./CommentsList";
const Comment = props => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Text>
        {props.comment.text} + {props.level}
      </Text>
      <CommentsList comments={props.comment.comments} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Comment;
```